# parentElement.parentElement.parentElement... alternative?

Tags: javascript, html, coding-style

I need to access the id of the most external div in my HTML element from a function executed by a button that is in the very inside of all the HTML elements.

I'm using `e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.id`
It works but it looks pretty ugly to me.

Is there another way to travel across that many parentElements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern browsers you can use [Element.closest(selectors)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
   console.log('Container id:', this.closest('.container').id);
})
```

```html
<div class="container" id="one">
  <div>
    <div>
       <button>Click me</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```